# Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s)

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I see below error every 5 secs in one of the nodes after server startup.  Started seeing this after upgrading spring boot 1.5 to 2.1.

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7d7d311c has been closed already
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090) [spring-context-5.1.18.RELEASE.jar:5.1.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1226) [spring-context-5.1.18.RELEASE.jar:5.1.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1773) `[spring-rabbit-2.1.17.RELEASE.jar:2.1.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1758) [spring-rabbit-2.1.17.RELEASE.jar:2.1.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1205) [spring-rabbit-2.1.17.RELEASE.jar:2.1.17.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1051) [spring-rabbit-2.1.17.RELEASE.jar:2.1.17.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
```

Comment: `Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error` Look in the server log; you would probably better asking this on the rabbitmq-users Google group where the rabbitmq engineers hang out - they will want you to show the server logs.

Comment: updated error logs

Comment: Your edit REMOVED important information, including the root cause. As I said, you need to look at the server logs.

Comment: Could you add more information? when does this happen? all the time, only at startup, after restarting rabbitmq service?